# Where can I download Ubuntu Touch 1.0?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I remember that today will release the official version 1.0, but where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in the release notes:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Refer to the documentation for installation steps for your specific device.